# Trouble with implementing a linked list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, linked-list

There's this HackerRank problem about implementing a linked list. It is pretty basic and I thought I'd do it in a jiffy since I'd done all kinds of linked list implementations in C++. But I'm stuck somewhere.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
class Solution:
    def display(self,head):
        current = head
        while current:
            print current.data,
            current = current.next  

    def insert(self,head,data): 
        new_node = Node(data)
        if head == None:
            head = new_node
        else:
            current = head
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_node

mylist= Solution()
T=int(input())
head=None
for i in range(T):
    data=int(input())
    head=mylist.insert(head,data)   
mylist.display(head)
```

Only the `insert` function is editable. The rest of the code is provided by HackerRank and cannot be changed. The code doesn't print anything at the end of the insertions, and when I tried to print out the values while inserting, it seemed like the `head` kept on moving forwards instead of staying at the beginning.

Comment: So you're asking us to pass your "interview" for you?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It might be a practice problem.

Comment: Yes, it's not any kind of interview. It's a very basic practice problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the `new_node` after all the elements, and also you are *not* returning the newly created node. Modify your `insert` method like this:

```
def insert(self,head,data): 
    new_node = Node(data)
    if head is not None:
        current = head
        new_node.next = current
    return new_node
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That seemed to do the trick. Although I had to make a few modifications since the question asked me to insert the element at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here:

```
head = mylist.insert(head, data)
```

the method `Solution.insert()` is not returning anything, therefore head is assigned None every time.

When done, `Solution.insert()` must return the `new_node` created

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because of the None check that you are doing in `insert` method.

```
if head == None:
        head = new_node
```

The `head` you are updating is local to the function `insert` and doesn't change `head` in the loop. So, `head` is always `None` in your loop.